# Django 1.8 AttributeError("'module' object has no attribute 'commit_unless_managed'")

Tags: python, django

Seems like django 1.8 deprecated support for commit_unless_managed module. Any suggestions on what alternatives one should use ?

Comment: You might find this article about [the changes to transaction management in Django 1.6](https://realpython.com/blog/python/transaction-management-with-django-1-6/) useful

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a drop in replacement. You should be switching to using the new apis like `transaction.atomic` that were introduced in Django 1.6.

The changes you have to make depend on which version are you upgrading from. If you were running Django 1.6 or 1.7 before, then `commit_unless_managed` was a no-op, and wasn't doing anything. If you're updating from an even earlier version, then you need to consider the effect of the change to [database-level autocommit in auto mode in Django 1.6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/transactions/#backwards-incompatibilities).